# How do you remove the axes unit labels from a corrplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, correlation

When I use the corrplot function in Matlab, the unit labels on the x and y axes look terrible.
I tried `set(gca,'XTickLabel',[]);`
but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: "look terrible" like a zombie or a vampire? scary. Hint: you may want to be clearer

Comment: `xlabel(gca,''); ylabel(gca,'');` ?

Comment: Sorry...I meant that because the scale of the units change from subplot to subplot, some range from 0 to 1, while others range from 0 to 1000...which makes the graph aesthetically displeasing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `gca` only returns the current axes, but `corrplot` creates *multiple* `axes` objects. You'll want to select all of them and set the `'XTickLabel'` to `[]`. You can use `findall` to get the handles to all of the `axes` objects.

```
set(findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes'), 'XTickLabel', [])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks:) It it makes perfect sense that there would be multiple axes...I wasn't aware of the findall function.Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Without any prior investigation from my part, I would recommend to assign the `gca` to a variable of your choosing, and then navigate through the `Children` until you get to a structure/class that presents the TickLabels you are finding on the plot itself. Then set those as empty sets `[]`. So, something like this:

`a = gca; b = a.Children;` 
%Analise b's properties
`set(b, 'XTickLabel',[]);`

Again, not stating that the first child has the field you want to set off. Just suggesting a way to go about the problem.

Comment: `axes` are not going to be children of another `axes` so this isn't going to work.

Comment: As the accepted answer showed, `axes`, can indeed be children of other `axes`

Comment: Actually if you look at the accepted answer (written by me) you'll see that it finds all figures that are children of *the current figure*. It's impossible for an axes to be a child of an axes: `axes('Parent', axes())`

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the clarification. Indeed I didn't notice the `gcf` instead of  `gca`. Kudos :)